# How to change/remove meta tag in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal

This is my first time using Drupal and i don't know PHP.
Here is my task:
I need to change the content in this tag:
`<meta name="robots" content="none">`
to
`<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">`
I've found how to add a new meta tag, but the old tag is still in code.
Now my html page looks like this:
`<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">`
....
`<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 9 (https://www.drupal.org)">`
....
`<meta name="robots" content="none">`
How can i remove the old tag or change the current.

I've created a new tag through meta-tag settings.
at this link
domain/admin/config/search/metatag

Comment: Search the code - maybe you'll find it as part of some twig template file.